# angularjs translate with two expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-translate

i am using angular translate to translate my angular website content but i faced a weird problem at some point in the website i use

```
<li   ng-repeat = "route in routes  id="route.PK">
                <a ng-if="route.name != 'Cars' && route.name != 'Workers' " ui-sref ="{{route.state}}">
                    <span class="title">{{route.name}}</span>
                </a>
    </li>
```

now i want to translate the route name which is returned from a web service,
every thing translated with angular-translate like this {{ 'key' | translate }}
but in my case the key is an expression! ,
so how i can use an expression inside another expression ?

Comment: Have you tried `{{ key | translate }}`?

Comment: `{{ route.name | translate }}`

Comment: yes i tried  {{ {{route.name}} | translate }} my problem is that the key is an expression itself

Comment: @dfsq thanks a lot it worked nicely :)